# Do you get more Experience on higher difficulties?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I noticed you seem to get more XP from Medi-gel pickups in Hardcore mode compared to regular mode.

Do you get more XP in single player mode when you're on higher difficulties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything to indicate that level XP is impacted by difficulty (in total, it *seems* to be capped at 69,000 for an entire playthrough), but the XP gained from picking up spare medi-gel is. The following table indicates the experience per excess medi-gel gained at each difficulty:

```
Difficulty | Experience
-----------+-----------
Narrative  |         25
Casual     |         25
Normal     |         50
Hardcore   |        100
Insanity   |        150
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you do more damage total due to increased enemy health, so yes, yes you do.

EDIT: No, that would not apply to single player.

Comment: Oops, I meant to specify single player